# GestureOverlayView hiding child view's event

Tags: android, gesture

I have followed [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGestures/article.html) tutorial to create a GestureOverlayView in my Android app. I have a color picker in my main view, over which I've added the gesture overlay. Now, the overlay works fine, but the color picker's color change event is not triggered when the overlay is on top. Here is the code for the activity.

```
    public class LightingActivity extends Activity implements OnColorChangedListener, OnGesturePerformedListener {
private ColorPicker picker;
private GestureLibrary gestureLib;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lighting);
    picker = (ColorPicker) findViewById(R.id.picker);
    //Register the event handler for color changes
    picker.setOnColorChangedListener(this);
    GestureOverlayView gestureOverlayView = new GestureOverlayView(this);
        View inflate = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_lighting, null);
    gestureOverlayView.addView(inflate);
    gestureOverlayView.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
    gestureLib = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
    if (!gestureLib.load()) {
      finish();
    }
    setContentView(gestureOverlayView);

}

@Override
public void onColorChanged(int color) {
    Toast.makeText(this, color, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
    ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = gestureLib.recognize(gesture);
    for (Prediction prediction : predictions) {
      if (prediction.score > 1.0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, prediction.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
      }
    }

}
}
```

I would like to have the gesture overlay, while still being able to trigger the onColorChanged event of the color picker view. Any help would be great! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this doesn't work because you are attaching listener to color picker which you don't use.

In this lines you are attaching listener to a color picker:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_lighting);
picker = (ColorPicker) findViewById(R.id.picker);
//Register the event handler for color changes
picker.setOnColorChangedListener(this);
```

And later you are creating a completely different view `gestureOverlayView` and previous view is simply not even shown.